# How do I get my text to be both bold and italic in iText?

Tags: fonts, styles, itext, bold, italic

I am trying to make my text both bold and italic at the same time for a paragraph in a PDF document using iText.

I can use either of these for bold and italic respectively, but not both simultaneously:

`Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.FontStyle.BOLD.ordinal());`

`Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.FontStyle.ITALIC.ordinal());`

How can I use both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLDITALIC);
```